# Javascript typedarrays sizing recomendations

Tags: javascript

I'm using float32arrays to store data. Imagine A,B numbers and imagine millions of points.
I'm going to have a buffer collection and the question is,
more buffers with lower bytes-size or less buffers with greater bytes-size?
What would be best ? 1MB, 4KB, 1KB?

- Some ideas for file I operations ?
- Same for ajax operations ?

What is the best size thinking in memory management done by web browsers?
Is there something like standard blocks ?

Thanks and excuse me if I'm asking begginer questions...